# Can you reconstitute dried morels in broth instead of water?

Tags: food-science, broth, mushrooms

I'm making some risotto this weekend, and I've always read to reconstitute dried mushrooms in water, but I haven't read anything for or against reconstitution in broth.

Would there be any reason not to do this, such as because the salts would change the way the shrooms did their job?

Answer (score 3):

The only reason I can think of against it is that your dried morels will have dirt in them and will contaminate your broth.

After the mushrooms have been re-hydrated, pick them up careful from the broth (they usually float).

Then, strain the broth using a coffee filter or a fine mesh strainer (@moscafj).

Use the remaining broth for your risotto.